# Can somebody explain the second argument of B-deduction in CPR?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, kant, idealism, critique-of-pure-reason

For me, the Transcendental Deduction aims at proving two things:

1. Categories or pure concepts of understanding must be applied to the manifold of intuitions, i.e, they are necessary for cognition.
2. Categories or pure concepts are legitimate insofar as they apply to intuitions.

I am not clear on the second part of the argument, nor can I find any passage directly aiming at the second point.

Also, I also understand that some people associate the second argument to Transcedental Schemata portion of the book. However, to me that section only elucidated how inner-sense/time is a common thread between the heterogeneous faculty of sensibility and understanding. That only proves 'how' the two faculties are linked, not why they should be.

Also, if you think this argument is rather given in Schemata, or ALSO given in schemata (since some papers indicate this as well), please explain that. Some papers also indicate that Schemata is redundant since this problem was solved in B-deduction, hence this question.

To summarise: I understand the argument for intuitions without concepts cannot constitute knowledge but what's the argument for the proposition that concepts without intuitions also cannot claim objective knowledge?

Comment: A knowledge of something has to be in correspondence with that something. How would empty concepts be brought into a correspondence with anything else without getting linked to intuitions?

Comment: Like that of metaphysics. That's knowledge that doesn't correspond to intuitions. So it is a knowledge about 'something' but that something is not intuitions. Kant needs to prove that the usage of categories should not be allowed to used on anything that doesn't have intuitions.

Comment: That is why pre-Kantian metaphysics was nonsensical, its practitioners overlooked that there was no way to bring it into any correspondence. So "like that" does not refer to anything. The burden is not on Kant to prove a negative, it is on those claiming a positive to produce a candidate for what that is supposed to be. Historical candidates include divine revelation and ESP, but epistemic magic, like all magic, is commonly viewed with understandable skepticism.

Comment: I honestly think you are too hung up on the term *objective* knowledge in the sense one would take it contemporarily (this is a translation of a text that is 240 years old, after all). What we call objective knowledge is rather framed as certain and necessary knowledge in Kant. It would probably be better to think in terms of actual knowledge about objects of experience. And since experience in general and its objects in particular are given through intuitions, the problem dissolves.

Comment: Hmm. I am still having trouble. See rationalists like Leibniz or Descartes never claimed that God or Soul are located in time or space. They said we have a priori reasoning that allows us to prove they exist. They never said they correspond to 'objects'. So when Kant terms them dogmatic, he needs to prove that the a priori 'reasoning' they are using, is only valid insofar as they do it on 'objects'. Now he has proved that objects correspond to intuitions. But he hasn't proved that a priori categories should only be applied to on objects, otherwise it is invalid.

Comment: Descartes claimed that God inserts innate "clear and distinct" ideas into our minds that reflect the reality accurately because he is not a deceiver. Leibniz claimed God insured "pre-established harmony". In Plato we have souls contemplating pure ideas prior to birth, and then unforgetting them, etc. If this is not dogmatic assertion of magical access to knowledge what is? These examples show that there is no "proving" what you ask to be proved. But theories that do not rely on  magic and miracles are preferable to the ones that do.

Comment: Yes, but my point is none of these arguments, of God and Soul, even mention space and time. All these three philosophers would be happy to concede that these entities are entities of 'pure reason' and have nothing to do with intuition. Kant's Critique of PURE REASON needs to establish that reason should not be applied to anything but intuitions. It's true that metaphysics before him do not apply concepts to intuitions, and there is no denying that, but why is it illegitimate to apply concepts without intuitions? This is, for me, the main objective of the book.

Comment: No, it does not. Kant's standard of proof is derived from law, not mathematics, and there is no ruling out supernatural "application" of reason "mathematically". Kant only needs to explain how it naturally arises from transcendental errors, which he does in CPR, and how it is inherently implausible because it endows us with divine powers, which he does when discussing *intellectus archetypus* in CJ. The point is not even that it is illegitimate to apply concepts without intuitions, it is not clear what "apply" would mean without implausible supernatural gimmicks.

Comment: "Kant only needs to explain how it naturally arises from transcendental errors". Since he called them 'errors', he needs to explain why they are errors in the first place. Now you say what does it even mean to 'apply'? Well metaphysics IS possible, people before Kant did it. What did they do wrong? They applied concepts without intuitions. Why is that wrong? This is what Kant has to prove. Kant cannot say metaphysics is 'impossible' only that it's illegitimate - since it obviously exists. You comment assumes that concepts without intuitions are nonsense and dogmatic, doesn't prove it.

Comment: Can you quote or refer to the source you cited? Thanks.

Comment: That the deduction is a legal concept in Kant should be part of any reasonably academic introduction to a translation. I think you ignored the main point Conifold made: In this method, you are free to assume anything, but you have to back it up with supporting arguments. Dogmatic is everything that makes assumptions without proper backup. Kant's point is that Reality is linked to experience, and that anything that is not either a necessary condition of the possibility of experience (this does not need intuition!) or itself derived from experience (hence intuition) can't be verifiable knowledge

Comment: "Reality is linked to experience". Descartes would say a big NO to that. He'll say experience (intuition in Kant's terminology) cannot be secured unless we apply apriori concepts in themselves. Thus, for Descartes reality is not linked to experience, it's linked to pure concepts of understanding being applied without any particulars. So now onus is on Kant to prove that reality is in fact linked to experience and pure concepts of understanding cannot account for reality alone.

Comment: However, I can claim this from all I have read that major scholars like Allison and Ameriks do say that TD in CPR does provide the proof that I am looking for. Unfortunately, I need a JSTOR account to read their papers on this particular topic haha.

Comment: By the way I found this sample - https://www.cambridgescholars.com/download/sample/61929. It does claim that can't prove the thing I am looking for but cannot buy the whole thing unfortunately.

Comment: I think you are referring to what Allison calls the ["discursivity thesis"](https://books.google.com/books?id=_qQTswzl504C&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=allison+concepts+without+intuitions+are+empty&source=bl&ots=WbZ0Z5KTzY&sig=ACfU3U0N70p0DqX0Rao61zeHmMJgB9PS1w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN7_yBgY_qAhUDlKwKHYu5CQgQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=allison%20concepts%20without%20intuitions%20are%20empty&f=false). As you can see, the argument is trivial on Kant's terms: rules of synthesis need data to subsume, and your version of Descartes's idea is just nonsensical, there is nothing left for Kant to "prove".

Answer (score 1):

The *Schematism* ***is*** the *Transcendental Deduction*. It's the **TD** continued. The reason why, I assume, Kant considered the "B" *Deduction* superior to the "A" version is exactly that it is structured in a way that immediately suggests that the *Schematism* constitutes the completion of the whole reasoning.

I only partially agree with your account of the *Deduction*. Indeed, the first part of the **TD-B** demonstrates that any object of  intuition is a possible object of judgement, which is broadly equivalent to what you said. But the *Deduction* doesn't provide any constraint on non-empirical use of the categories. Kant ***assumes*** that any object of our cognition must be externally given when he says that judgement is a mere act of combining/synthesis. Then, afterwards, he presents what he calls an 'indirect proof'  of this proposition in the *Transcendental Dialectic* by showing that going beyond the bounds of experience leads to dialectical contradictions and thus no knowledge can be acquired this way. The second part of the **TD-B** aims to show that objects intuited in space and time, necessarily subject to the categories as far as they're to be cognized, *can* at all be cognized, i.e. subjected to the categories. Kant speaks of *intellectual synthesis* (of intuitions as such) and *figurative synthesis* (of intuitions with some form). This provides a smooth transition into the *Schematism* chapter where pure time-determinations are finally derived from the categories (which is the sole purpose of the *Transcendental Deduction*).

Your confusion might stem from the fact that, indeed, the *Transcendental Deduction* with the *Schematism* elaborate the, using a phrase of Strawson, "bounds of sense" - from the *inside* of experience in which pure intellectual concepts and spatio-temporal intuitions. But to recognize a boundary isn't yet to forbid crossing it - that's the goal of the *Transcendental Dialectic* - that is the answer to the question in the last paragraph.